# Leaflet Routing Machine - Route Control: how to add a click listener to each instructions in the itinerary table?

Tags: javascript, html, razor, leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

currently, the default action when clicking part of a route is that it will zoom into that coordinate on the map.

im currently trying to add a text to speech that will say out the instructions for that particular part.

but how do i modify the click listener that is already built-in L.Routing.control?

the code below belongs to me:

```
var routeControl = L.Routing.control({
                waypoints: [
                    L.latLng(1.2734916210174561, 103.80210876464844),
                    L.latLng(1.314766, 103.765229)
                ],
                routeWhileDragging: true,
                geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim({ geocodingQueryParams: { "countrycodes": 'SG' } })

            }).addTo(map);

            routeControl.on('routeselected', function (e) {

                var coord = e.route.instructions;

                if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {

                    for (let i = 0; i < coord.length; i++)
                    {
                        //speak(coord[i].text);
                    }
                }
                else {
                      alert("your broswer does not support text to speech");
                }


            });
```

whereas this code below belongs to the original author which is loaded automatically when a route is found:
https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/blob/master/src/itinerary.js

```
_createItineraryContainer: function(r) {
            var container = this._itineraryBuilder.createContainer(),
                steps = this._itineraryBuilder.createStepsContainer(),
                i,
                instr,
                step,
                distance,
                text,
                icon;

            container.appendChild(steps);

            for (i = 0; i < r.instructions.length; i++) {
                instr = r.instructions[i];
                text = this._formatter.formatInstruction(instr, i);
                distance = this._formatter.formatDistance(instr.distance);
                icon = this._formatter.getIconName(instr, i);
                step = this._itineraryBuilder.createStep(text, distance, icon, steps);

                if(instr.index) {
                    this._addRowListeners(step, r.coordinates[instr.index]);
                }
            }

            return container;
        },

        _addRowListeners: function(row, coordinate) {
            L.DomEvent.addListener(row, 'mouseover', function() {
                this._marker = L.circleMarker(coordinate,
                    this.options.pointMarkerStyle).addTo(this._map);
            }, this);
            L.DomEvent.addListener(row, 'mouseout', function() {
                if (this._marker) {
                    this._map.removeLayer(this._marker);
                    delete this._marker;
                }
            }, this);
            L.DomEvent.addListener(row, 'click', function(e) {
                this._map.panTo(coordinate);
                L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
            }, this);
        },
```

so i'm trying to figure how do i access this to add my speech function

```
L.DomEvent.addListener(row, 'click', function(e) {
                this._map.panTo(coordinate);
                L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
            }, this);
```

when it's already been initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you have pasted, you can see that Leaflet Routing Machine uses something called a `ItineraryBuilder`, which is responsible for creating the DOM elements for the itinerary.

You can provide your own `ItineraryBuilder`, overriding the default builder, when creating the control. With your own custom implementation, you should be able to override the `createStep` method to make it add whatever listener you need.

One possible issue is that I see that the default `click` event handler calls `stopPropagation` on the event, which probably means that a listener you attach higher up in the DOM hierarchy will not see the click event. If this is the case, you would need a way to prevent `_addRowListeners` from being called, which to my memory currently does not exist.